# Не работает Tailwind в REACT

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind

Создал реакт приложение, подключил tailwind по инструкции https://tailwindcss.ru/docs/installation/ , пишу стили в className, но никаких изменений на странице нет. Перепробовал все что пишут в интернете и на данном портале.

Package.json -

```
{
  "name": "todos",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^9.7.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

index.js -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import Home from "./components/screens/Home/Home";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Сам компонент Home который подключаю в index.js для рендера -

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-purple-600">Home</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Ну и сам index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: Файл tailwind.config.js есть? Какое его содержимое?

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

Answer (score 0):

Если делали через Vite, то попробуйте:

`npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

`npx tailwindcss init -p`

**(Полные команды для создания проекта)**

```sh
npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react
cd my-project
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```